# Java dynamically create unspecified class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, casting, polymorphism

Quick question from anyone who knows java very well.
My interpretation is that this is impossible because classes have to be explicitly declared before run-time but I want a direct answer.

Can I in some way do this (short code):

```
Class foo extends Object; //There is a class named foo.

public Vector<Object> classVector = new Vector<Object>();

public static void main(String[] args){
    undefinedClassType = foo; //in some way
    classVector.add(new undefinedClassType); //Vector now has a Object that can be casted to foo.
}
```

Just wondering. Thank you for all of the help and responses.

Comment: Any reason you are extending object explicitly? Java classes already extend object implicitly.

Comment: But _why_ do you need to do this? Sounds like the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I am creating a save module for one of my games. I could make the module universal and put it on github if I could simplify the initial creation process for objects.

Comment: Right now I have a save file. When the game loads it looks into the save file and reads that it needs x number of trees and y number of bushes. 
If I have 100 different objects with varying quantities, it is tedious to write out if statements for each one, comparing each object with a list class names. If the class names are the same, x or y quantities of that object is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Java Reflection for that matter: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

You can compile a class at runtime using SDK tools and then load it into the Class loader, and then use reflection for instantiating it.

- Use [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) for compiling classes at runtime.
- Then, load it into your class loader using (the compiled class file needs to be in the classpath for it to be accessible to the class loader)

  Class theClass = Class.forName("YourClass");
- and finally use reflection for instantiating (this example is for a class with default constructor)

  YourClass loadedClass = (YourClass)theClass.newInstance();

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to try it and see how it works.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. Basically this was the code that made the difference: Item temp = (Item) (thisClass.newInstance());

thisClass is of class type Bowl. I made a bowl.

Answer (score 1):

The way to create an instance with an entirely new class during runtime is using `Proxy.getProxy()`.
You need to give it an array of interfaces to implement and an invocation handler that will invoke the actual methods called via this class.
Note that the array if interfaces could be just `Object`, but then you wouldn't be able to cast it into an instance whose methods are callable during compile time without reflection.